# In spacemacs org-mode, is there a way to select a region, and surround it with #+begin_quote and #+end_quote?

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, evil

I'm tired of typing `#+begin_quote` and the other one manually (couldn't type it, too tired). Is there a way to surround a region with this? I can't help but feel like there must already be a function for it that I just have to bind to some keystroke.

I'm a new emacs (spacemacs) user, using the vim keybindings, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if the same works on spacemacs, but it's worth trying: there is a set of predefined abbrevs in org-mode where you type

```
<q<TAB>
```

i.e. the '<' char, the q char and the TAB char which is expanded to

```
#+BEGIN_QUOTE

#+END_QUOTE
```

with the cursor left in between the two lines. For other abbreviations like this, check out the documentation of the variable `org-structure-template-alist`. The documentation of this feature can be found [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Easy-templates.html#Easy-templates).

Comment: Sweet, that's just the kind of thing I was looking for. It'd be nicer if it handled ranges, that is, be able to add that around a selected passage, but it works for now.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not handle a region AFAICT. When I want to surround a region, I use this mechanism to insert an empty template just before the region and then move the #+END part to the end of the region manually, by killing and yanking.